# What's the right way to map a polymorphic relationship with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, relationship

As the title may be a bit vague, here is an explanation of my problem (which is not easy to summarize into a concise title).

My problem is quite simple (what I'm trying to achieve seems really intuitive to me), though solving it might not be. I've two abstract classes representing tied concepts. As an example I choose Project and Task. A given project can have many tasks. These classes are abstract because there are different kind of projects and different kind of tasks, but projects and tasks kinds are the same. For example there are development project and development tasks (may seems a bit odd but this is a simplified example). Of course there are other kinds of projects and tasks but let's stick to these ones.

What I want to achieve is to map, with JPA, my relationship in the two abstract classes and benefit from it in the concrete classes. What complicates things is that I must also map inheritance: single table with discriminator, which is also part of classes ids. I add generic types to abstract classes to ensure that I can force concrete classes to refer to the right associated classes (DevelopmentProject tied to DevelopmentTask).

Problem is, whatever I try, I always get an error of some kind. What I seek here is somebody that've achieved something like this. I must tell you that I'm working with a legacy database (I'm well aware that current design suffer from many problems, but there is unfortunately nothing I can do for it).

To help you, I join the example code I made, that way you will see what I meant in the above paragraphs.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Project<T extends Task> {
    /* Fields */
    private ProjectId id;

    private List<T> tasks;

    /* Constructors */
    protected Project() {}

    public Project(ProjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /* Getters */
    @EmbeddedId
    public ProjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "project", targetEntity = Task.class)
    public List<T> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    /* Setters */
    public void setTasks(List<T> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class ProjectId {
    /* Fields */
    private Integer type;
    private Integer number;

    /* Constructors */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ProjectId() {} /* Empty constructor for hibernate */

    public ProjectId(Integer type, Integer number) {
        this.type = type;
        this.number = number;
    }

    /* Getters */
    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
    private Integer getType() { /* Only for Hibernate */
        return type;
    }

    @Column(name = "NUMBER", nullable = false)
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    /* Setters */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setType(Integer type) { /* Only for Hibernate */
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Task<P extends Project> {
    /* Fields */
    private TaskId id;

    private P project;

    /* Constructors */
    protected Task() {}

    public Task(TaskId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /* Getters */
    @EmbeddedId
    public TaskId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, targetEntity = Project.class)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE", referencedColumnName = "TYPE", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "NUMBER", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    public P getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    /* Setters */
    public void setId(TaskId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setProject(P project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class TaskId {
    /* Fields */
    private Integer type;
    private Integer projectNumber;
    private Integer number;

    /* Constructors */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private TaskId() {} /* Empty constructor for Hibernate */

    public TaskId(Integer type, Integer projectNumber, Integer number) {
        this.type = type;
        this.projectNumber = projectNumber;
        this.number = number;
    }

    /* Getters */
    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
    private Integer getType() { /* Only for Hibernate */
        return type;
    }

    @Column(name = "PROJECT_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    public Integer getProjectNumber() {
        return projectNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "NUMBER", nullable = false)
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    /* Setters */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setType(Integer type) { /* Only for Hibernate */
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setProjectNumber(Integer projectNumber) {
        this.projectNumber = projectNumber;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
public class DevelopmentProject extends Project<DevelopmentTask> {
    /* Constructors */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private DevelopmentProject() { /* Empty constructor for Hibernate */
        super();
    }

    public DevelopmentProject(DevelopmentProjectId id) {
        super(id);
    }
}


public class DevelopmentProjectId extends ProjectId {
    /* Constructors */
    public DevelopmentProjectId(Integer number) {
        super(1, number); /* Development type is forced */
    }
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
public class DevelopmentTask extends Task<DevelopmentProject> {
    /* Constructors */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private DevelopmentTask() { /* Empty constructor for Hibernate */
        super();
    }

    public DevelopmentTask(DevelopmentTaskId id) {
        super(id);
    }
}


public class DevelopmentTaskId extends TaskId {
    /* Constructors */
    public DevelopmentTaskId(Integer number) {
        super(1, number); /* Development type is forced */
    }
}
```

**EDIT** :
I corrected my example a bit (adding a projectNumber to Task, without it the relationship seems meanless, and even erroneous). I also added targetEntity on my relationships (I forgot it and you will see why below).

Now I will try to explain you my path until here.

- First of all I used MappedSuperclass annotation on my superclasses and no targetEntity on my relationships. That lead me to an error because of the generics: Hibernate didn't know what to map and suggest me to either remove generics, either use targetEntity, either use @Type (but that last one being Hibernate specific I prefer not to use it). So I set up targetEntity with Project.class and Task.class (at the superclasses level there were nothing else to do it seems).
- Then, I ran into another problem because of MappedSuperclass annotation. Hibernate tells me there is a reference to an unknown entity Project (or Task) [I'm adapting from there errors I got in my real project but I'm pretty sure I'll have the same once I'll manage to set those two tables up and tests them]. I googled that error and finally found that MappedSuperclass was the problem and that I could use Entity on abstract classes. So did I.
- After that, and that's the last error I got : repeated column mapping for column TYPE in DevelopmentProject. But If I try to set insertable = false and updatable = false everywhere this column is defined (id, relationship)... that doesn't change anything. I fear to have fallen in the same case of my precedent question : [How to map to attributes from embedded class to a single database column with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250542/how-to-map-to-attributes-from-embedded-class-to-a-single-database-column-with-jp). But in that case, there was an easy and not-too-ugly workaround. In this case I can't see it.

And I really wonder if someone have ever tried to achieve something like this and succeed, even if the solution is different, as it's as handy and elegant as possible.

Comment: Interesting question +1! Could you add some information, e.g. table creation DDL, and even more helpful would be some details about what errors you get?

Comment: I don't entirely follow the design requirement, but a simple question: are you aware of the existence of the annotation MappedSuperclass ?

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I'll edit my post and try to explain a bit more. For the moment I can't give you the DLL because I only created the classes for the examples (my real case was a bit complex and I preferred creating a simple dummy example). I will try my best to map this on real tables but I'll have to manage a local database on my PC. For the errors I can give you examples of what I had with my other work. And for MappedSuperclass, I know the annotation but when using relationships you must refer to entities (that's one of the errors I got earlier).

Comment: I think the implications of the generic types in your example are quite complex. In your scenario, it would be possible to define e.g. `public class AnotherDevelopmentProject extends Project<DevelopmentTask>` or `public class AnotherDevelopmentTask extends Task<DevelopmentProject>`. What would you expect that to mean?

Comment: I agree with you, that's one of the weakness of this representation... But I didn't manage to force, with generics, two subclasses to be bound with each other and not with any other else. I start to believe I will have to move the relationships at subclasses level or to do things differently, but it really annoys me as this relationship will exist every time.

Comment: It seems that I'm really stucked because of this 'TYPE' column which is used as a discriminator and in the id. The fact is that, even without the relationship, I got the error 'repeated column TYPE'... And It seems to be linked to the fact that insertable = false and updatable = false are of no use for ID's... If someone sees a workaround, it's much welcome !